# RSpec before confusion with devise mappings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

so I need to set a devise mapping for my tests to work properly. Per https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-%28and-RSpec%29, I added

```
describe Api::SessionsController do
  before(:each) do
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
  end
  ...
end
```

This works fine. However, since I'll be reusing this across multiple specs, I wanted to put it in a module in a support folder. Hence:

## support/devise_helper.rb

```
module Controllers
  module DeviseHelpers
    def set_devise_mapping
      before(:each) do
        @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:api_user]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I include the module via:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Controllers::DeviseHelpers, type: :controller
end
```

And then in the spec:

```
describe Api::SessionsController do
  set_devise_mapping
end
```

and I get the following error:

```
ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-3.2.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:626:in `method_missing':
 `set_devise_mapping` is not available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
 It is only available from within individual examples (e.g. `it` blocks) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). (RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::WrongScopeError)
```

Why do I get this? This is what the github example linked above does. Also it works without the method. I tried using :context and putting it in different places but I get an error no matter where I put it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method **set_devise_mapping** inside **describe** but not **it**

instead of (this work when using in **it** blocks)

> config.include Controllers::DeviseHelpers, type: :controller

must (this work when using in **describe** blocks)

> config.extend Controllers::DeviseHelpers, type: :controller

Comment: This causes an error: uninitialized constant Controllers.